# Can someone explain SUM Function task?

Tags: javascript, nested, sum

**Create a function sum that will work like that: sum(a)(b) = a+b and accepts any number of brackets.**

Task is taken from [this learning source](http://javascript.info/tutorial/closures).

```js
function sum(a) {
  
  var sum = a 
  
  function f(b) {
    sum += b
    return f
  }
  
  f.toString = function() { return sum }
  
  return f
}

alert( sum(1)(2) )  // 3
alert( sum(5)(-1)(2) )  // 6
alert( sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) )  // 0
alert( sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) )  // 15
```

Can anyone explain actually how it works? A and B arguements are fine, but where in the code do we use other arguements (in cases when more than two of them)?
Why do we need to use toString method here? Is it related to problem or just for alert.
Also, I tried the same code with *console.log* instead of *alert*, and it didn't worked. What's the problem here?

Comment: Please make the title, and the question, useful for others in the future. Be more specific. What about this code do you not understand? Which part of the relevant learning resource does not adequately explain it? And which learning resource is it?

Comment: Works fine switching `alert` to `console.log`. If it didn't work for you what errors did it throw? what part of the code don't you understand?

Comment: It showed me in console instead of numbers just { [Function: f] toString: [Function] }. I guess it's because we are dealing with strings, so I add "+" in front of console.log (+sum), seems to work now. 

Considering code, I added above. Mainly I don't get how we use all arguements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a the alert out of the picture, and you have this code being invoked:

```
sum(1)(2)
```

You are probably confused about the double parenthesis - what's happening here is you are first invoking the `sum` function, and passing it the argument of `1`. When you pass `1` to `sum`, you are setting `1` to a local variable named `sum`, then a function is declared `f` and used as the return value from the `sum` function.

As a result, since you invoked `sum` and got back a function (`f`), you can then call *that* function with parameter `2`.

So in essence, you're really doing this:

```
var someFunc= sum(1);
someFunc(2);
```

Which can be re-written like this:

```
sum(1)(2);
```

Comment: I got it, sort of using function value as an arguement. Double parenthesis is somewhat easy. I stuck on multiple parenthesis task understanding. I mean,  how does this code get the number of our arguements and pass there values them to function.

Comment: This code is run synchronously. When you run `sum(1)(2)`, `sum` is run first, and `f` is returned, then `f` is immediately invoked since you invoked it with `2`. So at any given time, you are only invoking ONE function and passing ONE parameter. Not sure what you mean by ''how does the code get the arguments"....you are passing them in...

Comment: @KarénMarkosyan Glad that pulled things together

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(a) {  
var sum = a 
//return function f;
function f(b) {
sum += b
return f
}
//override of toString to print sum
f.toString = function() { return sum }
return f;
}
alert(sum(1)(2));
```

Explanation for alert(sum(1)(2))

1.sum(1) gets executed first returning a closure with sum value 1

```
f(b){
    sum=sum+b; //sum=1 here from sum(1)
}
```

2.Next f(2) gets called

```
sum=sum+b// sum=1,b=2 so sum=3
```

and f gets returned.since f is overridden it prints sum value which is 3